# Cannot boot into Lucid Lynx

Tags: ubuntu, boot, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, bookmarks

I upgraded from Karmic Koala to Lucid Lynx beta, was working fine for a while (was even rebooting). But, after some time, it is not booting and i cant find a solution.
I have tried installing the `grub` again, doesn't help.

Well, the problem is all my settings, bookmarks and passwords are blocked in that partition. I cant find where the Chrome stores bookmarks in Ubuntu.

Can you help me either getting my system rebooted or getting the bookmarks ?

Thanks.
p.s. I am currently on liveusb.

---

Edit:
The grub menu comes, and it runs (as it should for 6-7 secs) and then a blank screen comes and after some time, there is an error some what like below

> Busybox 1.3
>   Job control turned off
>   Cannot access tty
>   /bin/sh ..

[grub.cfg file at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ur1LTY2V)

---

Edit 2:
The same thing happens when i boot with recovery option. (something like below)

> [2.176345] device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.259
>   [6.873452] scsi 5:0:0:0 Direct access

after waiting for some time, the following shows

> BusyBox v1.13.3 built0in shell(ash)
>   Enter help for a list of built-in commands
>   /bin/sh: cant access tty: job control turned off (in initramfs)

Also, earlier when i was able to boot into Lucid, I used to edit the boot option like below :

```
recordfail
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,5)
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-16-generic root=/dev/sda5 ro  
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-16-generic
```

Now, the above runs for 2-3 seconds,

```
recovery required
recovery done
mounted filesystem
```

after that its a complete black screen (for like atleast 3-4 mins)

Comment: when you get this error, you're attempting to boot into the standard kernel, yes?  does the same thing happen if you choose the recovery kernel?

Comment: @~quack: updated