# Correct way to re-install grub in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, grub

What is the standard/correct way to re-install grub2?
I am using liveusb right now and [i am unable to boot into Ubuntu on my hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/123369/cannot-boot-into-lucid-lynx).

Partitions are as follows:

```
/dev/sda1               1        3917    31463271    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            3918       10444    52428127+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3           10445       15671    41985877+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           15672       19457    30411045    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   *       15672       17711    16386268+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6           17712       19457    14024713+  83  Linux
```

Pleas help.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is `grub-install`, so if you e.g. want to install `grub` on `/dev/sda` you would run

```
grub-install hd0
```

or

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

If you use some other, additional boot manager in `/dev/sda` adjust the parameter to `grub-install`.

For some details see `info grub-install`.

**EDIT**

Assuming you are installing to `/dev/sda` (replace with whatever partition you use), you might want to back-up your boot sector with

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=boot_sector.bak bs=512 count=1
```

so you could restore it later in case of errors with

```
dd if=boot_sector.bak of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: I have boot partition in /dev/sda5 and ubuntu also in /dev/sda5. So, i should "grub-install /dev/sda" or "grub-install /dev/sda5" ?

Comment: That depends on where you keep your boot manager(s). Do you use some other boot manager besides `grub`?

Comment: @honk: i am only using grub2

Comment: @xenon: he's asking because of the NTFS partitions in sda1-3. What handles booting those? If it's grub2 for everything, then it is likely that the boot sector in on your disk is where you should install (/dev/sda instead of /dev/sda5)

Comment: is there anything else to be done after "grub-install". it completed without any errors

Comment: I just added some backup instructions.

Comment: @kbyrd: previously, i had installed the grub on /dev/sda5.

Comment: @xenon: No. That's it. 
@honk: That '512' value in dd backs up the code portion and the partition table. If you use '446' instead you can keep and restore just the boot loader code, which is useful if the destination drive is larger or has a different layout.