# How to install only GRUB bootloader and put chainloader to load automatically Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, grub

I broke my boot partition but Windows is still installed and unaccessible. I had only Windows installed on my computer before.

How can I install GRUB and chainload it to automatically load Windows? I have Ubuntu installed on a USB stick.

Comment: Why don't you just use a windows cd to repair the boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/123401/62814

Comment: Need more information, Which distribution of Ubuntu, new or old?  There are a few alternate Ubuntu install disks available that guide you through repairing a broken GRUB.  It is important to know which because I believe newer versions switched to GRUB2.